# How to detect "abc" in abc.domain.com or abc.sub.domain.com using PHP?

Tags: php, subdomain, hostname

I need to detect if a user is accessing my site from a certain sub-domain. How can I detect the following example and flag it using PHP? I only want to detect if "abc" is the sub-domain and nothing more, but it has to work with various other domains after "abc".

- http://abc.domain.com/
- http://abc.domain/
- http://abc.sub.domain.com/

Yes, they're on the "abc" sub-domain.

- http://domain.com/
- http://xyz.domain.com/
- http://www.domain/
- http://sub.domain.com/
- http://xyz.sub.domain.com/

No, they're not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the subdomain:

```
array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the **HTTP_HOST** or **SERVER_NAME** in your **$_SERVER** variable.

```
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'abc.domain.com') !== false) {
    //do something
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the host name from within the `$_SERVER` superglobal like this:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

There are then any number of ways to determine if this value begins with `abc`.  The easiest might simply be `stripos`

```
if(stripos('abc', $domain) === 0) {
    // you found it
}
```

Note that the use of `===` instead of `==` is VERY important here. If you used `==` and the substring was not found in `$domain`, `stripos` would return `false`, which with `== 0` would evaluate as `true` in your conditional.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if( explode( '.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] )[0] === 'abc' ) {
    //do something
}
?>
```

That will explode server name in parts divided by `.`, so it will compare the first part of the domain name with the string abc.

The explode(x,x)**[N]** thing is only possible in PHP 5.4+ (or 5.3+, I don't remember correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your web server to redirect all your subdomains to a single PHP file where you can make up an error or redirect the user via the `header()` function with something like...

```
header('Location: http://domain.com');
```

Also, because you're sure that the particular PHP file is being accessed because of a subdomain, then you can do something like...

```
$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
list($subdomain) = explode('.', $url, 2);
$subdomain = trim(strtolower($subdomain));
```

And then use the `$subdomain` variable the way you like (eg. print it)...

```
echo $subdomain;
```

Just in case. For the Apache configuration, you need to modify the `VirtualHost` for redirecting your subdomains to a PHP file for processing.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias *.domain.com
DocumentRoot /website/directory/page.php
</VirtualHost>
```

**NOTE**

1.) To restart Apache.
2.) Apache will give you warning that the directory does NOT exist. It's true, because you are providing a file path instead of a directory path. But this will work.